# How to add VM args using pom.xml plugin

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, vmargs

I have tried below ways but nothing work... 
i am trying to access jmx remotely from server.

```
         <jvmArgs>
         <jvmArg>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999</jvmArg>
        <jvmArg>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false</jvmArg>
          <jvmArg>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false</jvmArg>
        </jvmArgs>

        <!-- <systemPropertyVariables> 
                                   <com.sun.management.jmxremote.port>9999</com.sun.management.jmxremote.port> 
                       <com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate>false</com.sun.management.jmxremote.a uthenticate> 
                     <com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl>false</com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl> 
                 </systemPropertyVariables> -->

                 <!-- <jvmArguments> 
                 <jvmArgument>- Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999</jvmArgument> 
                 <jvmArgument>- Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false</jvmArgument> 
                 <jvmArgument>- Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false</jvmArgument> 
                </jvmArguments> -->
```

I also tried

```
 <options>
            <option>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999</option> 
            <option>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false</option> 
            <option>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false</option> 
            </options>
```

Comment: for what do you want to add the vmargs? Compiling, testing, running your application? With what maven goal do you do this? You should show more of your pom.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do this in few different ways.

**Using the Maven Compiler Plugin**
You can use the `compilerArgs` property of the plugin to specify the Xmx, Xms, Xss VM arguments.
Below is an example

```
<project>
    [...]
    <build>
      [...]
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.10.1</version>
           <configuration>
             <compilerArgs>
                  <arg>-Xmx512M</arg>   // You can provide comma separated values if you have more than one
             </compilerArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
       [...]
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
```

Refer to the [Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html) for more details.

**Using the Maven Surefire Plugin**
You can use the `argLine` property of the plugin to specify the Xmx, Xms, Xss VM arguments.
Below is an example

```
</project>    
    [...]
    <build>
      [...]
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
           <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx512M</argLine>   // You can provide comma separated values if you have more than one
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
       [...]
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
```

Refer to the [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

**Can be done in POM file as follows :**

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                    <argLine>
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```