# How to pass VM Options in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I need the following vm options to be passed into maven.

```
-Dvertx.disableFileCPResolving=true  
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml 
-Dlogger-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory 
-DAPP_ID=9757632
```

At present I am passing them via the IDE (Intellij) and everything is working fine. (See screenshot)

[image: VM Options]

But how can I add them as part of the Maven project, possibly via POM file or a resource file?

Tried the following in my POM file based on the suggestion in this page but it doesn't work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39751176/9401029

```
<properties>
    <vertx.disableFileCPResolving>true</vertx.disableFileCPResolving>
    <log4j.configurationFile>log4j2.xml </log4j.configurationFile>
    <vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name>io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory</vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name>
    <APP_ID>9757632</APP_ID>

</properties>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>${vertx.disableFileCPResolving}</arg>
                    <arg>${log4j.configurationFile}</arg>
                    <arg>${vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name}</arg>
                    <arg>${APP_ID}</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Saw another example using the file JVMARGS (no extension) which holds following values.

```
-Dvertx.disableFileCPResolving=true  
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml 
-Dlogger-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.Log4j2LogDelegateFactory 
-DAPP_ID=9757632
```

Placed this file at the root level and within resource folder. That doesn't work either.

Please advice how to pass these values into my maven project, preferably via POM file. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to pass variables to Maven itself (e.g., to control the build process), or to some application that Maven is building? You seem to be trying both operations, but that have completely different purposes. If you want to pass variables to your own program at runtime, are you running it from Maven?

Comment: @KevinBoone I want to pass variables to my own program at runtime and yes, its a maven project.

Comment: If you want to pass to your own application at runtime it make no sense to put those things into the build process.

Comment: @khmarbaise Guess am wording this wrongly. These values need to get picked up when I do my build. I just want to add these as part of my POM file in some way or a file like JVMARGS. Is it possible.

Answer (score 4):

Maven has a gazillion ways to run Java code, through various plug-ins -- and they don't all use the same methods to pass JVM command-line switches to the running program.

For example, the `exec` plugin [1] respects the environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS`. This is a *system* environment variable, not a Java environment variable.

So on Linux, to run a program under Maven with a specific `-Xmx` setting I might do

```
$ MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2000m" mvn exec:java
```

But note that you'd need to set `MAVEN_OPTS` in a way that is appropriate for your platform. For an IDE on Windows, you might need to use the Control Panel to do this. Or your IDE might provide a way to set the environment variable when it runs Maven -- that depends on the IDE.

So the short answer, I guess, is that you need to find exactly which execution plug-in you're using in Maven, and look at the documentation for that plug-in to see how to configure it to use the appropriate JVM settings.

In the end, though, you're probably not going to be running your application under Maven in the long term. You'll need to find a way to specific JVM settings independently of Maven -- in a script, or batch file, for example.

[1] https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html